# Resampling a saddle DataFrame to hourly 15min and 5min periods in Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, resampling, saddle

I'm trying to use some stock tick data in the format ["unixtime", "price", "amount"]

It's simple to load the CSV file with CsvParser, but how do I go about resampling the data to use olhc (open, high, low, close) for the price and sum for the amount, for a specific period in Julia (hourly, 15min, 5 min, etc...)?

he DataFrame after converting the unixtime to a date is something like:

```
DataFrame:
                           date price  amount
[1,]    2011-09-13T13:53:36 UTC   5.8     1.0
[2,]    2011-09-13T13:53:44 UTC  5.83     3.0
[3,]    2011-09-13T13:53:49 UTC   5.9     1.0
[4,]    2011-09-13T13:53:54 UTC   6.0    20.0
[5,]    2011-09-13T14:32:53 UTC  5.95 12.4521
[6,]    2011-09-13T14:35:04 UTC  5.88   7.458
```

Is there any outside package to resample the data or is there any function in saddle that accomplishes this?